# How to remove an element from a list when a certain values are in the elements?

Tags: r, list

I have a list as followed:

```
> combination
[[1]]
[1]  1  10  7 15

[[2]]
[1]  1  10  7 15

[[3]]
[1]  10  3  10 15

[[4]]
[1]  10  3  7 15

[[5]]
[1]  10  10  5 15
```

How do I remove those that contain example both 7 and 10?

Assume I am removing elements that contain both 7 and 10, it should look like this in the end:

```
> combination
[[3]]
[1]  10  3  10 15

[[5]]
[1]  10  10  5 15
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) !all(c(7, 10) %in% x), combination)

#[[1]]
#[1] 10  3 10 15

#[[2]]
#[1] 10 10  5 15
```

---

Other options could be :

2) Using `sapply`

```
combination[sapply(combination, function(x) !all(c(7, 10) %in% x))]
```

3) Using `purrr::discard`

```
purrr::discard(combination, ~all(c(7, 10) %in% .x))
```

4) Using `purrr::keep`

```
purrr::keep(combination, ~!all(c(7, 10) %in% .x))
```

**data**

```
combination <- list(c(1, 10, 7, 15), c(1, 10, 7, 15), c(10,  3,  10, 15), 
                    c(10 , 3 , 7, 15), c(10,  10,  5, 15))
```

Comment: Do I have to enter the ```Filter``` code several times if I want to omit not just elements containing 7 and 10, but also omit elements containing 3 and 10?

Comment: @WeiShung No, you don't have to enter the code several times. You can do `Filter(function(x) !(all(c(7, 10) %in% x | c(3, 10) %in% x)), combination)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sum` on logical vector to subset

```
combination[sapply(combination, function(x) sum(c(7, 10) %in% x)) != 2]
#[[1]]
#[1] 10  3 10 15

#[[2]]
#[1] 10 10  5 15
```

#### data

```
combination <- list(c(1, 10, 7, 15), c(1, 10, 7, 15), c(10,  3,  10, 15), 
                    c(10 , 3 , 7, 15), c(10,  10,  5, 15))
```